# Calling a WCF from iOS application

Tags: iphone, wcf

I need to call methods in a WCF to recieve JSONP data? Any advice how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [sample from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472488.aspx). I was able to implement JSON WCF services quiet easily by following the sample. (the sample download link is towards the end of the article)

Comment: The WCF is already made. But I don't manage to call methods of it :(

Comment: Solved it myself. Guess it was just a stupid question. Thanks anyways!

Comment: can you at least answer your question :) i need to know the same thing

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab It depends on the WCF. How the service is exposed. Json services is usually available through a http request.